# Ant Migration Tool: INVALID_OPERATION - INVALID_OPERATION:Too many files in zip

Tags: deployment, metadata-api, ant, continuous-integration

Now I'm trying to deploy bunch of custom objects to my Developer Org. using Ant Migration Tool.
All these custom objects are from our Production org, and the final goal is to setup CI in our development process. So, for now I need to deploy all metadata to Developer Org, where all development will be performed. The problem is that I can't even upload Custom Objects and take next error from Ant:

```
BUILD FAILED 
C:\Users\new\Projects\SFDC\Aorta\sfdc-hwks-dev1\src\build.xml:49: Failed to 
submit request to https://eu11.salesforce.com/services/Soap/m/37.0/00D0Y000000Yc6u 
for <my.user.name@email.com>. 

Error: {http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata}
INVALID_OPERATION - INVALID_OPERATION: Too many files in zip
```

NOTE: I have 153 Custom Objects here. Is this to many for Salesforce?
Here is my package.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>CustomObject</name>
    </types>

    <version>37.0</version>
</Package>
```

And build.xml:

```
<target name="deployUnpackaged">
  <sf:deploy username="${sf.username}" password="${sf.password}" sessionId="${sf.sessionId}" serverurl="${sf.serverurl}" maxPoll="${sf.maxPoll}" deployRoot="./" rollbackOnError="true" testLevel="NoTestRun"/>
</target>
```

Comment: Did u chked cudtom object limit has nit crossed in your dev org

Comment: @Ankuli The error message is - 'Too many files in zip'. The deployment process even bot started on the org.

Comment: What can you do to check this, by deploying few of object or in chucks of objects.

Comment: @Ankuli, the problem is realy strange, when I moved all `objects` folder to the new place - **srcDeploy** and changed **build.xml** attribute `deployRoot="./srcDeploy"`, and the process started to upload metadata.